# MPU-9150 (IMU) - what happens at fullscale range boundaries?

Tags: serial, i2c, imu

We're debating the use of the MPU-9150 IMU in an application. This IMU has a user settable full scale range for the accelerometer (e.g. 2g, 4g, etc) and gyroscope (200dps, 400dps, etc).

Suppose I set the values at 2g and 200dps - what happens at the boundaries of these ranges? Are the values ceiling/floored (i.e. an acceleration of 3g-4g results in 2g sent to back from the sensor), or do the values roll over?

Comment: A good question for the manufacturer, but I would certainly expect it to rail at the maximum number. Time for recovery from overload would be another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPU 6050 pegs at either end of the range (you can see the red series flat lining):

[image]

I assume the 9050 does the same, though haven't tested it. We use the 6050 in production.

Comment: It should considering the 9150 has a 6050 in it. Will go with this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the range selection changes an amplifier gain so that the ADC input range corresponds to the selected g range.  If the sensor output is outside of this range, then it will simply be clipped to one end of the ADC range (min or max ADC code).